# How to remove layers with Keras Functional model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to modify layers at the *beginning* of ResNet50, so include_top=False will not work. I know there are issues with using standard methods for sequential models since ResNet is a functional model due to the skip connections.

Basically I want to take out the first 20 layers or so and replace them with my own. Can I do this with the functional API?

Thanks

Comment: Generally It's doable what you're looking for. But please be more specific what do you mean by first 20 layer out and so and replace with your own stuff!

Comment: Well I didn't want to get too technical but I was going to remove the first pooling/ normalization/ etc layers and the first conv_2x block. I want to keep all deeper layers with the weights. Then I want to add a structure similar to the original back to the beginning of the model, except it will be revised so that I can input larger images.

Comment: But everything I find on google for removing layers of a model is for sequential models.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this in the future, I finally figured it out after countless google searches and posts to multiple forums. I didn't find the answer anywhere, just played around with functions until I found a solution.

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))      

truncated_model = Model(inputs = base_model.layers[7].input, outputs = base_model.layers[-1].output) #truncates the functional model from layer 7 to final layer  

keras.utils.plot_model(truncated_model, "mini_resnet.png", show_shapes=True) #Plots the functional model graph
```